# Custom Task Queue in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I have created a new task queue and defined it in queue.yaml

I am not sure how to start adding tasks to this queue?

with the default queue it is simple taskqueue.add(...)

how do we do it for a custom queue?

Answer (score 10):

You may specify which queue to add a task to by passing a `queue_name` parameter ([documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html#Task_add)).  `queue_name` defaults to "default".  Example:

```
 taskqueue.Task(url='...', params={...}).add(queue_name='my_custom_queue')
```

Comment: When i do this, i am getting an "TypeError: Invalid arguments: queue_name
" error?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like one cannot pass `queue_name` to `taskqueue.add()`, so you have to use the `Task` class to create the task and then pass `queue_name` to `Task.add()`.  I have updated the example in my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I've also created a [feature request issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3283) that asks `taskqueue.add()` to handle a `queue_name` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
final Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("queuename);
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/path/to/queue"); //as defined in web.xml
```